# laravel 5.1 file_put_contents wrong path

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

So I am using laravel 5.1 on ubuntu with nginx and php-fpm, I am having a little issue with my sessions. I have done all the permissions (`chown to nginx/php user and group and chmod 777 on storage`) however I think there is another issue.

The session file is created as I can see it on the server however when laravel is trying to write to it I don't think it can find the file see bellow:

```
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'file_put_contents(/54dc94489b4c137d744f0427ce2c7e5e): failed to open stream: Permission denied',
```

Is there an issue with laravel finding the session path ? I am not really sure what to do, I have edited the filtsystem class and hard coded the path to the session directory however that isn't the correct solution.

Comment: Bingo! No one told me this. :)

Comment: Must add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create 'storage/framework/views'